# SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file how to give password

Tags: c, terminal, openssl

SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file function or SSL_CTX_check_private_key function asks for password in terminal for my private key. I would like to pass this password in some OpenSSL function, so one of these functions don't asks about it in terminal. My application will get password from command line or from dialog window.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The function you are looking for is:

```
void SSL_CTX_set_default_passwd_cb(SSL_CTX *ctx, pem_password_cb *cb);
```

The callback function argument `pem_password_cb` has the signature:

```
int pem_passwd_cb(char *buf, int size, int rwflag, void *userdata);
```

`buf` is the destination buffer for the passphrase.  `size` gives the size of the buffer.  `rwflag` indicates whether the passphrase is for a decryption (read) or encryption (write) operation.

`*userdata` is arbitrary data the application can specify to be passed to the callback.  You can set the `userdata` via the function:

```
void SSL_CTX_set_default_passwd_cb_userdata(SSL_CTX *ctx, void *u);
```

See the [`SSL_CTX_set_default_passwd_cb(3)`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/ssl/SSL_CTX_set_default_passwd_cb.html) man page for more information.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't have enough reputation to vote up your post. Your solution was good, but I don't have manual pages for this function.

Comment: @nintyfan no worries; I updated my answer with a link to the official web version of the man page.  Feel free to come back and upvote the answer when you have enough rep :)